# If statement to clear (not delete) the cell B1 which does not meet criteria in the cell A1. Same for lines below

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

In column A there are 24 titles. In column B there is similar data.

I want a "Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()" to clear contents from cell B1 in which text does not equal cell A1. Same for all lines down the table.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You have `if` in your question and checking equality you can find out quite easily?

Comment: Doing your coding while you do something else isn't a definition of "helping" accepted on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for each loop to do the job.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim range As range

Set range = Worksheets("Sheet1").range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cell In range
    If cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -1) Then
        cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim range As range

Set range = Worksheets("KA failas").range("H1:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cell In range
    If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(0, -1) Then
        cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next cell

End Sub

Comment: Changed it to above (<>) as i needed to delete not equal data. Thank You very much. Helped a lot!

Comment: Dariusz - if I would want to clear contents from column C also in case column B data is not equal to column A data? Does this change a lot?

Comment: Not really, just add below cell.ClearContents this line: cell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Keep safe!